# SQL SELECT id and count of items in same table

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL table columns...

```
id | item | position | set
---------------------------    
 1 |   1  |     1    | 1
 2 |   1  |     1    | 2
 3 |   2  |     2    | 1
 4 |   3  |     2    | 2
```

In a *single* query I need to get all the ids of rows that match `set='1'` while simultaneously counting how many instances in the same table that it's `item` number is referenced regardless of the `set`.

Here is what I've been tinkering with so far...

```
SELECT 
    j1.item, 
    (SELECT count(j1.item) FROM table_join AS j2) AS count 
FROM 
    table_join AS j1 
WHERE 
    j1.set = '1';
```

...though the subquery is returning multiple rows. With the above data the first item should have a count of 2, all the other items should have a count of 1.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. You need one set one way, yet all sets another way? Is this homework?

Comment: It's a dedicated JOIN table for HTML templates. When deleting templates I need to count if the items are used by more than one template, if so I should NOT delete that item. I try to keep my databases clean from unused expired data. Also I'm using MySQL but because Oracle is evil I've written it to be as compatible as possible with PostgreSQL for when I make the transition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT
    j.id
,   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_join i WHERE i.item = j.item) AS count
FROM table_join j
WHERE set='1'
```

This is similar to your query, but the subquery is coordinated with the outer query with the `WHERE` clause.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e6c3c/1).

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative worth testing for performance, you can use a `JOIN` instead of a dependent subquery;

```sql
SELECT tj.id, COUNT(tj2.id) count
FROM table_join tj
LEFT JOIN table_join tj2 ON tj.item = tj2.item
WHERE tj.`set`=1
GROUP BY tj.id
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f3be/1).

Comment: I'm all for better performance if I get the same exact desired results; I just am not sure how to benchmark the two queries to figure out which is better?

Comment: @John If it's not a very frequent query or directly noticeable with the amount of data you have, it shouldn't matter much which query you use. Just added it as something to consider/test if you see the original query running slowly later. Testing with real data/indexing is always the best way to evaluate it later.